# How to embed Youtube Video in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5LJgSQbZ9o4" 
        title="YouTube video player" 
        frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

This tag doesn't display on my page for some reason:

[image]

It says content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your codes and it works well in my case:
[image]

Have you blocked the video with your own chrome settings?check the settings or try with other browser.

Comment: It doesn't work with razor engine and asp.net core 6 probably

Comment: I have tried on all browsers mozilla, chrome and edge